# Problem with accessing an array from inside a promise

Tags: javascript

So I have this code which essentially sends a message with `results` as a string **then** sends a message again to ask the user to select one of the elements inside the `results` array and **then** tries to assign the array content of results inside the myObj property using `this` which does not work (returns undefined).

I've read that `this` can refer to

> the global object in a function.

can that apply here?.

Here is the sample:

```js
                        let myObj = {
                           testArray: []
                        };

                        let results = [1,2,3]´;

                        send(results.join("\n"))//sends array as message
                            .then(m => { //premise returns the same array as message
                                send(`Please type a number.`)
                                    .then(m => { //same for reply, returns `Please type a number`
                                        obj = {
                                            testArray: this.results //<---- here results is undefined
                                        };
                                    })
                                    .catch(err => console.error(err));
                            })
                            .catch(err => {
                                console.error(err);
                            })
                    })
```

Would there be anyway to use the `this` keyword to get access to the results array defined earlier and if yes what would be it's role in this situation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Save the reference in a `const` before the promise. `const _this = this` . Then in the promise just use `_this.results`.

Comment: The window object is the Global Object in the Browser. Any Global Variables or Functions can be accessed as properties of the window object. Because this changes depends on the context.

Comment: What is `obj`? Also a global variable? What role does `m` play? It seems the user's input is not influencing the results...

Comment: You used `results` already as the first `send` argument, so why do you want it differently the second time you use `results`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @VladimirBogomolov, would you mind explaining why that would work and what does `_this` actually do there? thanks.

Comment: @SImplestDev I suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: ...I see a lot more problems coming once you want to actually use `obj`. Maybe you should ask about the bigger picture, so we can better answer to what you really need here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window object is the Global Object in the Browser. Any Global Variables or Functions can be accessed as properties of the window object. Because 'this' depends on the context.

Either assign 'this' to a variable and then reuse that variable inside the function or just say results(which may not be great option). Unless you have multiple 'results' variable defined you wont have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `testArray: this.results` with only `testArray: results` as `results` is a variable only